# Destructor not being called when leaving scope

Tags: c++, scope, destructor

I am learning memory management in C++ and I don't get the why only some of the destructors are called when leaving scope. In the code below, only obj1 destructor is called when myfunc ends, not for the dynamically allocated obj2.

```
int myfunc (cl1 *oarg) {

    cout << "myfunc called" << std::endl;
    cl1 obj1(222,"NY");
    cl1 *obj2;
    obj2= new cl1;
    oarg->disp();
    obj2 -> ~cl1 ;

}
```

Here is the destructor I have :

```
cl1 :: ~cl1 () {

std::cout<< " cl1 destructor called"<<std::endl;
std::cout << this->data << std::endl; //just to identify the obj
delete [] str;
str = NULL ;

};
```

Comment: Thx a lot everyone, however i have small doubt - if a dynamically allocated object is not deleted in the function itself, can it be used outside the scope of the function ? Or in other words, should every function that has a new in it have a delete also ? And why wont calling th destructor free the memory -- the destructor has a delete defined in it . Oh wait, it deletes only part of the object right ?

Comment: Yes, a dynamically allocated object can be used outside the function it was allocated in. it can be used until you `delete` it, wherever you do that.

Comment: A function with a `new` and a corresponding `delete` in it can probably be written without dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you allocate a object using `new`

```
obj2= new cl1;
```

Then unless you call `delete` on it, its destructor won't be called implicitly.

EDIT: As @David, meantions in comments, One may call destructor of an object explicitly but in my experience there is rarely a need to manually call the destructor unless one is using placement new version of new.

Variables on stack are implicitly cleaned up(by calling their destructors) when their scope ends.

Dynamically allocated objects are not implicitly cleaned, it is the responsibility of the user to clean them up explicitly calling `delete`.

This is the very reason one should not use raw pointers but use smart pointers.

Comment: *Then unless you call `delete` on it, its destructor won't be called* is not technically correct. You can manually call the destructor (and the code in the question is *almost* doing it!): `obj2->~cl1()` (the difference from the code in the question is the *call* i.e. `()`). Note that this will **not free** the memory, but will call the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically allocated objects are *your responsibility* - you need to *explicitly* clean them up. Automatic objects (such as `obj1`) are cleaned up when the scope exits, *automatically*. In this case, before the scope exits - explicitly call `delete obj2`. NOTE: this line `obj2 -> ~cl1` - does not do anything - the `delete` will take care of triggering the destructor correctly.

Comment: It is not true that calling the destructor explicitly is not going to do anything. The point is - it shouldn't be done in this case

Comment: @VJo, look very carefully at that line of code, infact that line would be a compile error...

Comment: @Nim You are right. But if he would make it compile (call the destructor correctly) - it would still be a wrong thing to do. @jalf missing `()` after `~c1'

Answer (score 2):

`obj1` is an object of type `cl1`, with *automatic storage duration* (It is allocated on the stack, and its lifetime is determined by the scope it is in)

`obj1` is an object of type `cl1*`. That is, *it is a pointer*. The pointer also has automatic storage duration, but the object it points to does not. It points to a dynamically-allocated object in the free-store.

When you leave the scope, then the objects with automatic storage duration get destroyed. `obj1` gets destroyed, calling your destructor. And `obj2` also gets destroyed, but `obj2` isn't of type `cl1`, so it doesn't call `cl1`'s destructor. It is a pointer, and it does nothing special when it is destroyed.

Pointers don't own the objects they point to, and so they do nothing to ensure the pointed-to object gets destroyed or cleaned up. (If you want an "owning" pointer, that's what smart pointer classes are for)

Consider that you can easily have multiple pointers pointing to the same object.

If a pointer automatically deleted the object it pointed to, then that would lead to errors. An object pointed to by two different pointers would get deleted twice.

Answer (score 1):

> `obj2 -> ~cl1 ;`

Don't do this! Use `delete obj2;` instead.

**Addendum**
What you were trying to do was to call the destructor explicitly. Your code does not do that.  Your code is getting the address of the destructor and then dropping it into the bit bucket. Your code is a no-op. The correct way to explicitly call the destructor is `obj2->~cli();`.

Explicitly calling the destructor is usually something you should not do.

What you should do is to delete the memory created by `new`. The correct way to do that is to use the `delete` operator. This automatically calls the destructor **and** releases the memory. The destructor does not release the memory. Failing to use delete results in a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Destructors are called automatically when an object that was created on the stack goes out of scope.

With dynamically allocated objects, you need to call `delete obj`. delete will automatically call your destructor for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `delete` for dynamically allocated objects:

```
delete obj2;
```

this calls the destructor and frees memory. You'll be much better off using smart pointers for managing such objects - they will call `delete` for you even in case of exception being thrown between `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `delete` operator to destrory an object and not call its destructor directtly. Secondly, by doing `new` you are telling the compiler that you *dont* want to delete the object when it goes out of the scope. In such case you need to explictly fo `delete objj2;` to delete the object.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr instead of raw pointer.
It the best way to avoid memory leaks or double free.

That is the right way in modern C++.

```
int myfunc (cl1 *oarg) 
{
    cout << "myfunc called" << std::endl;
    cl1 obj1(222,"NY");
    std::unique_ptr<cl1> obj2( new cl1 );
    oarg->disp();
}
```